# Can ellipsis be followed by a pronoun like "YOU"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to quote someone's tweet and planning to use the ellipsis as a pause in my sentence (due to showing an aggressive attitude)

*

> You... SNOB! Stop gossiping about me!

Correct?

Comment: It's perfectly valid.  The ellipsis indicates a pause, and it would not be uncommon for someone to pause and take a breath before shouting "SNOB!".

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is better you simply say 'You SNOB! Stop gossiping about me!' because the ellipsis causes it to sound like you are hesitating and can't think up a good insult. However, the ellipsis is certainly not grammatically incorrect, so posting like that is perfectly fine; it is simply that you don't sound aggressive like that.

Comment: I actually downvoted this when I started to read your answer—then reversed that when I got to your third sentence. It's better if you lead with an objective answer first, and only then provide a personal opinion. I would recommend editing this answer and making the first sentence simply: "The ellipsis is certainly not grammatically incorrect, so posting like that is perfectly fine." After that you can continue to discuss style and meaning.